# How to make a copy of a file in android?

Tags: java, android

In my app I want to save a copy of a certain file with a different name (which I get from user)

Do I really need to open the contents of the file and write it to another file?

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Pre Java7, I think the answer is yes you do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/MoveaFile.htm

Comment: check older [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9096319/990029)

Answer (score 363, accepted):

To copy a file and save it to your destination path you can use the method below.

```
public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        try {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

On API 19+ you can use Java Automatic Resource Management:

```
public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to check in this code that the file is successfully copied or not?

Comment: @mohitum007 if the file fails to copy then an exception is thrown. use a try catch block when calling the method.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, the streams would not be closed until they're garbage collected, and [that's not good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515975/closing-streams-in-java#comment5185168_515981). Consider closing them in `finally`.

Comment: @Pang. You are right. What's worse, in/out.close() must be called or otherwise there will be a resource leakage in the underlying OS, since the GC will never close the open file descriptors. GC can't close OS resources external to the JVM like file-descriptors or sockets. Those must always be closed in a finally clause programatically or use try-with-resource new syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Please, close both Streams inside a finally, if there is an Excepcion, your streams memory won't be collected.

Comment: @Rakhi  when i copy large size file it is taking time so can you tell me what should i do for fast copy in one folder to another thanks

Comment: @pradeepbishnoi you can try to use larger buffer: 
byte[] buf = new byte[choose_large_value];

Comment: After API 19 you can use Java automatic resource management by defining the in and out streams in the opening of your try `try (
                FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src); 
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst)
        ) {`

Comment: [`Files.copy` **is** available](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%252520java.nio.file.Path,%252520java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) as of API Level 26.

Comment: ` > 0` is bug. Sometimes it is possible to have read return 0 bytes and then the write with 0 bytes can throw an exception. It's better to check for `!= -1`

Answer (score 137):

Alternatively, you can use [FileChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) to copy a file. It *might* be faster than the byte copy method when copying a large file. [You can't use it if your file is bigger than 2GB though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076472/filechannel-map-integer-max-value-limit-error)

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: transferTo can throw an exception and in that case you are leaving streams open. Just like Pang and Nima commented in accepted answer.

Comment: Also, transferTo should be called inside of loop since it does not guarantee that it will transfer the total amount requested.

Comment: I tried your solution and it fails for me with the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/AppProj/IMG_20150626_214946.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` at the `FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);` step. According to the text I realize, that the file doesn't exist, so I check it and call `dst.mkdir();` if needed, but it still doesn't help. I also tried to check `dst.canWrite();` and it returned `false`. May this is the source of the problem? And yes, I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`.

Comment: @ViktorBrešan After API 19 you can use Java automatic resource management by defining the in and out streams in the opening of your try `try ( FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src); FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst) ) {`

Comment: Is there any way to make this solution publish its progress to `onProgressUpdate`, so I could show it in a ProgressBar? In the accepted solution I can calculate progress in the while loop, but I can't see how to do it here.

Comment: @MikeB. If you're running it on API 23 or above, try checking for the runtime permission.

Comment: even better with try with resources --> try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src); FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst))

Answer (score 64):

Kotlin extension for it

```
fun File.copyTo(file: File) {
    inputStream().use { input ->
        file.outputStream().use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

This is simple on Android O (API 26), As you see:

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  public static void copy(File origin, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(origin.toPath(), dest.toPath());
  }
```

Answer (score 20):

These worked nice for me

```
public static void copyFileOrDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir) {

    try {
        File src = new File(srcDir);
        File dst = new File(dstDir, src.getName());

        if (src.isDirectory()) {

            String files[] = src.list();
            int filesLength = files.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                String src1 = (new File(src, files[i]).getPath());
                String dst1 = dst.getPath();
                copyFileOrDirectory(src1, dst1);

            }
        } else {
            copyFile(src, dst);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Much simpler now with Kotlin:

```
 File("originalFileDir", "originalFile.name")
            .copyTo(File("newFileDir", "newFile.name"), true)
```

`true`or`false` is for overwriting the destination file

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-to.html

Comment: Not so simple if your File comes from a Gallery intent Uri.

Comment: Read the comments below that answer: "This answer is actively harmful and does not deserve the votes it get. It fails if the Uri is a content:// or any other non-file Uri." (I did upvote - I just wanted to clarify it's not a silver-bullet)

Answer (score 11):

It might be too late for an answer but the most convenient way is using

`FileUtils`'s

`static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile)`

e.g. this is what I did

`

```
private String copy(String original, int copyNumber){
    String copy_path = path + "_copy" + copyNumber;
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(new File(path), new File(copy_path));
            return copy_path;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`

Comment: FileUtils does not exist natively in Android.

Comment: But there's a library made by Apache that do this and more:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: I think Fileutils requires inputstream  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils

Answer (score 8):

in kotlin , just :

```
val fileSrc : File = File("srcPath")
val fileDest : File = File("destPath")

fileSrc.copyTo(fileDest)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that actually closes the input/output streams if an error occurs while copying. This solution utilizes apache Commons IO IOUtils methods for both copying and handling the closing of streams.

```
    public void copyFile(File src, File dst)  {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(src);
            out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "IOException occurred.", ioe);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of *copy* you should use *copyStream*.

Comment: to make it more simpler. we can use try-with which will close streams automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**in Kotlin: a short way**

```
// fromPath : Path the file you want to copy 
// toPath :   The path where you want to save the file
// fileName : name of the file that you want to copy
// newFileName: New name for the copied file (you can put the fileName too instead of put a new name)    

val toPathF = File(toPath)
if (!toPathF.exists()) {
   path.mkdir()
}

File(fromPath, fileName).copyTo(File(toPath, fileName), replace)
```

this is work for any file like images and videos

Answer (score 1):

now in kotlin you could just use

```
file1.copyTo(file2)
```

where file1 is an object of the original file and file2 is an object of the new file you want to copy to

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy way...!

```java
import android.os.FileUtils;

try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile); 
     OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile) ){
                
     FileUtils.copy(in, out); 

}catch(Exception e){
     Log.d("ReactNative","Error copying file: "+e.getMessage());
}
```