# Copy a file: FileChannel vs Input/OutputStream

Tags: android, file, copy, filechannel

Is using a `FileChannel` the newer and better way to copy a file in Android (as opposed to making an `InputStream` and `OutputStream`)?

And if so, how do I specify a `File` in assets to copy to any other location?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21286928/2649012

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get the File reference for the source when it is in assets?

Comment: Then you'll use an InputStream.