# Copy apk in sdcard from list

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i have retrieve all apk installed in my device and I created a list in which I can see them. On click over an item, I have created a dialog.I would that on positive button copy the apk of that position in a folder I created in the sdcard.  So far I tried and I can show in a toast the app folder and position of each apk but I don't understand how can I copy that apk I have selected. This is the code

```
.setPositiveButton("Copy apk", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogapk, int id)
               {
                   // TODO: Implement this method
                   final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                   mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                   final List pkapplist = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

                   for (Object o : pkapplist) {
                       ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) o;
                       file = new File( info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Boh "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
                   try
                   {    
                       process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp " + file + " " + customfolder);
                   }
                   catch (IOException e)
                   {

                   }

               }


        });
```

Custom folder is the folder I have created in this way

`final File customfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"BackupApk");`

Actually it creates a file and not a folder of size of application itself..I don't know exactly what it is doing!! Thanks. If needs the adapter let me know

Comment: Are you checking if folder is not present den customfolder.mkDir();

Comment: nope for reality..  That's the problem i think.. Or one of problems.. i don't remember which code use for entire to check and create a new folder

Comment: Try `dd`, because most of andorid production systems won't have cp or mv

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you declare `"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` permission in your Manifest file?
2) `cp` command is missing on Android system commands: `/system/bin/sh: cp: not found` 
3) When creating `customfolder` you are missing `customfolder.mkdirs()` statement to *actually* create this custom dir on the external storage 
4) Try following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android)

**Update**
Tried to implement your logic.
Following solution (taken from aforementioned link) proved itself as working one (it actually backups APK files onto the */sdcard*):

```
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupDir.getAbsolutePath() +  File.separator + file.getName());
FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
inStream.close();
outStream.close();
```

Comment: 1) Done, 2)i think it works, 3)mmh..maybe you're right, 4)No needs root to do this operation :) but however not wors :(

Answer (score 0):

```
File  Folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"YourFolder");
        if(!Folder.exists()){
            Folder.mkdirs();
        }
```

This is the code to check n create

Comment: ok done..thanks.. by the way still not copy the apk. have you got solutions?