# How to copy/cut/paste files in android api >= 8?

Tags: android, copy-paste

Writing a custom file explorer for my needs, I would like to let users copy/cut/paste files (filtered : *.epd) or folders. But api 11 requirement is too high for me.

I did not find whether the compatibility v7 or above has a workround for this : where can I learn more if it is such case ?

Of course, **it must have the standard behaviours** : let the users choosing if he must overwrite files, if he wants to cancel tranfer on the least error ... In order to be inside the android developper philosophy : *"Let me get the final words"* (end user point of view).

I've tried to implement my custom Clipboard, but **it is such an horrible pain and spaghetti code candidate** ... Also looked for an implementation at github : but did not find anyone suitable (only for text copy).

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android?

Comment: Thanks but you did not paid attention to the bold sentences ... I need standard behaviours

Comment: for that you have to write your own logic, like before copying file , look into destination directoty if same file is present or not. Depends on the result you can show dialog to user that he wants to oveewrite file or not.

Comment: Knowing an existing project doing so ? Because I feel like I can't do it without spaghetti code.

Comment: No I don't know any exsiting libarary for the same. If I found, will update you :)