# android copy system file with root results in empty file

Tags: android, root

I'm trying to copy files from /system/lib/hw folder to another folder (in device storage).
I have root and I use the following code to do that:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat source > destination");
```

The files get copied but are empty.
Is there another way to do it? copying other files using this code succeeds, this only happens for files in /system/lib/hw directory.

Comment: do you already give root permission to your application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a copy of a file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android) It doesn't matter do you have root or not this code should work. If you don't have root access you will get an exception.

Comment: Yes, the issue is not with root as all other copy operations succeed, only files from /system/lib/hw are copied empty

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I can copy files from other directories. The issue is that files are copied empty

Comment: I'm not  a linux expert , but that folder has references to mounted devices - camera, usb devices, etc... so they doesn't contain no bytes, just streams... so you can use them to get images from mounted camera and other hardware related stuff...

Comment: Thanks, I am not a Linux expert either, do you know of some example on how to do that?