# use BufferedWriter to write same data to multiple files

Tags: java, android, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm interested in writing some data I'm receiving into two different files (same data).

In my code, I'm using `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter` to write the data to files, and I want, as a backup, to write the same data on the local storage and on the SD card.

My question is if I need to implement this with 2 `FileWriters` and 2 `BufferedWriters`, or is there a way to use the same `BufferedWriter` for both files?

Is there a more efficient way to implement this task?

Comment: If it is a backup, both file should **not** be written at the same time, but the backup should be only written from time to time after controlling that the initial file *looks* correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reusing the *same* writer isn't possible - unless you spend the time to implement your own special subclass of Writer that writes its output into multiple files at the same point in time. (to then pass an instance of such a `CopyingWriter` to the [ctor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#BufferedWriter(java.io.Writer)) of BufferedWriter).

But I suggest to **not** do that. Instead: write the file **once**. Then use other, existing technology to **copy** the output file.

Always aim for simplicity. You intend to create a very special solution, where one writer writes to *n* files. But there is no need to do that. Write your file once, then copy it *n* times. This approach doesn't require "innovation" - you just need to use what already exists (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android) for example).

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll do that :)