# Copy file from one folder to another

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy the file as the Android path comes, without success, although it already existed as permissions on AndroidManifest, it's as if the file did not exist or know it there.
Here's a piece of code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String origem = uri.getPath();
                File src = new File(origem);
                if(src.isFile()){
                    Log.d(TAG,src.toString());
                }

                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                root = new File(root.toString(), "Kcollector/importa/import.csv");

                try {
                    copy(src,root,true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public static void copy(File origem, File destino, boolean overwrite) throws IOException{
    Date date = new Date();
    if (destino.exists() && !overwrite){
        System.err.println(destino.getName()+" já existe, ignorando...");
        return;
    }
    FileInputStream fisOrigem = new FileInputStream(origem);
    FileOutputStream fisDestino = new FileOutputStream(destino);
    FileChannel fcOrigem = fisOrigem.getChannel();
    FileChannel fcDestino = fisDestino.getChannel();
    fcOrigem.transferTo(0, fcOrigem.size(), fcDestino);
    fisOrigem.close();
    fisDestino.close();
    Long time = new Date().getTime() - date.getTime();
    System.out.println("Saiu copy"+time);
}
```

The error that returns me when trying to copy:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_storage/Kcollector/importa/kvendasajustado.csv (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: StackOverflow is an English speaking site. Please ask your question in English.

Comment: The Log.d line (TAG, src.toString ()); returns me the path of the file:/external_storage/Kcollector/importa/kvendasajustado.csv

Comment: ¿Habla usted ingles? Do you speak English?

Comment: Sorry, I already translated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the runtime permissions or use the method indicated in the first [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android)

```
public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        try {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Finally check the url if is formed good.
Otherwise you can de bug with a breakpoint(search these words), and find exactly where the problem comes from

Comment: Do you have the method that checks the permission for READ and WRITE?