# How to copy Images/Videos from DocumentFile Object to Gallery Folder using MediaStore Api

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I gained access to this folder using Document Tree Intent :-

```java
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AExampleApp%2FMedia%2F.hiddenMedia
```

The URI of a image present in the above folder :-

```java
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AExampleFolder%2FMedia%2F.hiddenMedia/document/primary%3AExampleFolder%2FMedia%2F.hiddenMedia%2FCristiano.jpg
```

Now I have that image as a DocumentFile and its URI from the above folder.

```java
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, fileUri);
```

`fileUri` is the URI of the DocumentFile.

Note :- The files in the folder cannot be accessed via MediaStore API because the folder is hidden

Usually this DocumentFile can be either an Image or a Video file.
How do I copy the Image/Video from the DocumentFile to `Pictures/My App` using MediaStore API.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `from the DocumentFile to the public Gallery Folder` From the Document file? But DocumentFIle is not a location to begin with. ` public Gallery Folder` What do you consider to be the public gallery folder? If you have a DocumentFile uri then the file is already in such a storage location that it is scanned by the media store and hence visible with Gallery apps.

Comment: But of course if you have a DocumentFile uri you can make a copy of the file using a mediastore uri that you obtain first. It is only pretty unclear where you want the copy to land.

Comment: @blackapps The URI of the DocumentFile is of a Hidden folder that i gained access via Document Intent. and I want the copy to land on `Pictures/My Folder`

Comment: `via Document Intent. ` Pretty vague! Why so vague? A few wordt more and it would have been exact.

Comment: Well all you want is doable. But why dont you react to all the things i said?

Comment: @blackapps I have changed and added more info to the question. Let me know if you need more Info. Since you mentioned its doable, Can you share how its possible?

Comment: Just request a writable uri from the media store using the insert() method. Then open an inputstream for your source uri and an outputstream for the destination uri. Then copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps!
All I had to do was to request a writable URI from the `MediaStore` using the `insert()` method and then open a `InputStream` for source URI and `OutputStream` for destination URI.

Code for above action :-

```java
public void saveFile(Uri sourceUri, String fileName, String mimeType) throws IOException{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Uri destinationUri;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);

        if (fileName.endsWith(".mp4")){
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + "/MyFolder");
            destinationUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyFolder");
            destinationUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        }

        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceUri);
        OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(destinationUri);

        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The File has been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Note :- You have to add the `Commons-io` dependency in your build.gradle file to access `IOUtils.copy()` function

If you find any better way to do this, Do share it!

Comment: Is this method IOUtils.copy() deprecated? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Tarsila Costalonga When I Used it, that method was not deprecated, And for me it worked fine...

Comment: @TarsilaCostalonga `FileUtils` can be used instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/73040236/11880323