# Why does Spark RDD partition has 2GB limit for HDFS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have get an error when using mllib RandomForest to train data. As my dataset is huge and the default partition is relative small. so an exception thrown indicating that "Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE" ,the orignal stack trace as following,

> 15/04/16 14:13:03 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 19.0 in
>   stage 6.0  (TID 120, 10.215.149.47):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
>   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:828)   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:123) at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:132) at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetLocal(BlockManager.scala:517)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocal(BlockManager.scala:432)
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:618)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:146)
>   at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:70)

The Integer.MAX_SIZE is 2GB, it seems that some partition out of memory. So i repartiton my rdd partition to 1000, so that each partition could hold far less data as before. Finally, the problem is solved!!!

So, my question is :
Why partition size has the 2G limit? It seems that there is no configure set for the limit in the spark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076472/filechannel-map-integer-max-value-limit-error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic abstraction for blocks in spark is a `ByteBuffer`, which unfortunately has a limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE (~2GB).

It is a [critical issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1476) which prevents use of spark with very large datasets.
Increasing the number of partitions can resolve it (like in OP's case), but is not always feasible, for instance when there is large chain of transformations part of which can increase data (flatMap etc) or in cases where data is skewed.

The solution proposed is to come up with an abstraction like [LargeByteBuffer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6190) which can support list of bytebuffers for a block. This impacts overall spark architecture, so it has remained unresolved for quite a while.

Comment: Are there any known good work-arounds for this issue?  Increase number of partitions, or decrease? Split up RDDs into parts, run your command, and then union? Turn off Kryo? Use dataframes?  I am encountering the 2GB bug on attempting to simply (re)partition by key an RDD of modest size (84GB) and low skew (AFAIK). I have my memory requests per executor, per master node, per Java, etc. all cranked up as far as they'll go, and I'm currently attempting to partition this RDD across 6800 partitions.  Is that too many, and actually causing my problem?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235 which in Sep 2016 appears to be a fix.

Comment: @pd40, is the fix in an official release now?

Comment: As of today I believe it is only partially fixed

Answer (score 1):

the problem is when using datastores like Casandra, HBase, or Accumulo the block size is based on the datastore splits (which can be over 10 gig).  when loading data from these datastores you have to immediately repartitions with 1000s of partitions so you can operated the data without blowing the 2gig limit.

most people that use spark are not really using large data; to them if it is bigger that excel can hold or tableau is is big data to them; mostly data scientist who use quality data or use a sample size small enough to work with the limit.

when processing large volumes of data, i end of having to go back to mapreduce and only used spark once the data has been cleaned up.  this is unfortunate however, the majority of the spark community has no interest in addressing the issue.

a simple solution would be to create an abstraction and use bytearray as default; however, allow to overload a spark job with an 64bit data pointer to handle the large jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spark 2.4.0 release](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html) removes this limit by replicating block data as a stream. See [Spark-24926](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24296) for details.