# Unable to use SparkSQL to read from table with row size > 2GB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use SparkSQL to export my database to my S3 in Parquet format.

One of my tables contains row size > 2GB. The Spark was submitted with `--conf spark.executor.memory=21g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=9g --conf spark.executor.cores=8`.

It seems there is a limitation from Spark: [Maximum size of rows in Spark jobs using Avro/Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081121/maximum-size-of-rows-in-spark-jobs-using-avro-parquet). But not sure if it’s the case.

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Have you check the number of partitions for the dataframe? Sometimes Increasing the number of partitions could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `spark.driver.maxResultSize` is `1g`. You might need to set it higher if you encounter this issue:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized
results of XXXX tasks (X.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (X.0 GB)
```

**Reference**

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/configuration.html#application-properties