# Confused about 2gb limit in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

I read the 2 GB limits in spark due to bytebuffer limitation of lnteger.MAX_INT. 
I understood that memory block size can't exceed due to this, so any record in an RDD partition should be less than 2gb.

But I read here([Why does Spark RDD partition has 2GB limit for HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689719/why-does-spark-rdd-partition-has-2gb-limit-for-hdfs)) an RDD partition itself can't exceed 2gb. And  repartition into smaller partitions worked.
Is it true?  Please help me understand it..

Comment: Is this a programming question or a question about server administration?  (If its the latter, this isn't the right place to ask)

Comment: It is a programming doubt, we were facing issue with it application and trying to analyse reason