# Reading file >4GB file in java

Tags: java, stream, nio

I have mainframe data file which is greater than 4GB. I need to read and process the data for every 500 bytes. I have tried using FileChannel, however I am getting error with message Integer.Max_VALUE exceeded

```
public void getFileContent(String fileName) {
    RandomAccessFile aFile = null;
    FileChannel inChannel = null;
    try {
        aFile = new RandomAccessFile(Paths.get(fileName).toFile(), "r");
        inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(500 * 100000);
        while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
                byte[] data = new byte[500];
                buffer.get(data);
                processData(new String(data));
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO
    } finally {
        try {
            inChannel.close();
            aFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me out with a solution?

Comment: Show the exception & stack trace

Comment: You could try wrapping a `FileInputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Check out this - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076472/why-does-filechannel-map-take-up-to-integer-max-value-of-data Will give you an idea about the error you are getting

Comment: BTW, consider using [try-with-resources](https://www.google.fi/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=try-with-resources), it's more handy for closeable resource management

Comment: If you're parsing characters, why not just use a Reader?  For example, `try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) { … }`

Comment: The placement of the `buffer.clear();` within the innermost loop is definitely not what you want—besides all the unnecessary data copying. Besides that, I don’t believe you that you get the exception you have described, simply due to the `catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO
    }` part…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst problem of you code is the

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO
}
```

part, which implies that you won’t notice any exceptions thrown by your code. Since there is nothing in the JRE printing a “Integer.Max_VALUE exceeded” message, that problem must be connected to your `processData` method.

It might be worth noting that this method will be invoked way too often with repeated data.

Your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
```

implies that you iterate as many times as there are bytes within the buffer, up to `500 * 100000` times. You are extracting `500` bytes from the buffer in each iteration, processing a total of up to `500 * 500 * 100000` bytes after each `read`, but since you have a misplaced `buffer.clear();` at the end of the loop body, you will never experience a `BufferUnderflowException`. Instead, you will invoke `processData` each of the up to `500 * 100000` times with the first `500` bytes of the buffer.

But the whole conversion from bytes to a `String` is unnecessarily verbose and contains unnecessary copy operations. Instead of implementing this yourself, you can and should just use a `Reader`.

Besides that, your code makes a strange detour. It starts with a Java 7 API, `Paths.get`, to convert it to a legacy `File` object, create a legacy `RandomAccessFile` to eventually acquire a `FileChannel`. If you have a `Path` and want a `FileChannel`, you should open it directly via [`FileChannel.open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). And, of course, use a `try(…) { … }` statement to ensure proper closing.

But, as said, if you want to process the contents as `String`s, you surely want to use a `Reader` instead:

```
public void getFileContent(String fileName) {
    try( Reader reader=Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName)) ) {
        CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(500 * 100000);
        while(reader.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            while(buffer.remaining()>500) {
                processData(buffer.slice().limit(500).toString());
                buffer.position(buffer.position()+500);
            }
            buffer.compact();
        }
        // there might be a remaining chunk of less than 500 characters
        if(buffer.position()>0) {
            processData(buffer.flip().toString());
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // the *minimum* to do:
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // TODO real exception handling
    }
}
```

There is no problem with processing files >4GB, I just tested it with a 8GB file. Note that the code above uses the `UTF-8` encoding. If you want to retain the behavior of your original code of using whatever happens to be your system’s default encoding, you may create the `Reader` using

```
Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset())
```

instead.